# Rails, country_select, save country name to model database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, form-for

Need some help here...

I am using the country_select gem to pull the countries into a drop-down list in a form:

```
<%= f.label :country_code, "Country Traveled:" %>
<%= f.country_select :country_code, prompt: "Select a country" %>
```

The code above pulls the full country name (i.e., France, Germany, etc.) on my form, but it stores the country_code (FR, DE) in my model database.

How do I store the full country name in my model instead? Your reply GREATLY appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have forked the original country_select gem and modified it to have country name as the value when sending the form the backend. You can fork, clone or point the gem in your gemfile to my repository :

```
gem 'country_select', git: 'https://github.com/alibabajan/country_select.git'
```

Comment: Thanks, Ali! Can I ask what you changed? Interested to see what was done so I know. Thanks!

Comment: change was very miner, in the `country_options_for` method of tag_helper.rb i changed the return value from [name,code] to [name,name] so that the options tag use country name both for value and display. you can see what I changed [here](https://github.com/alibabajan/country_select/commit/2c56b876740647a9d3493eea2a1a635474ce3b20) you can also do it yourself :-)

Comment: Amazing! I noticed the change as well. Cheers to you!

Comment: glad I could help :) please clone or fork it for yourself to have a copy and use that in your application, in case I accidentally delete or modify this gem.